# React based Forms that could render via json

Tags: json, forms, validation, reactjs

I am looking for any ReactJS based lib that utilizes json as input and renders the HTML accordingly. Bonus if it can do automatic validation for the end user's input. Example it takes a json input having an array and renders it as HTML select control.

Also the lib should have the possibility to be used without nodejs, I mean in a simple web application like for example Asp.Net MVC based web app. Much better if it has examples and good documentation.